# AssertJ on list of Optionals

Tags: java, assertj

I have a List of Optionals, like `List<Optional<String>> optionals` and I like to use `assertj` on it to assert several things.

But I fail to do this properly - I only find examples on a single Optional.

Of course I can do all checks by myself like

`Assertions.assertThat(s).allMatch(s1 -> s1.isPresent() && s1.get().equals("foo"));`

and chain those, but I still have the feeling, that there is a more smart way via the api.

Do I miss something here or is there no support for `List<Optional<T>>`in assertj ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AssertJ doesn't seems to provide utils for collections of optionals, but you can iterate your list and perform your assertions on every item.

```java
list.forEach(element -> assertThat(element)
        .isPresent()
        .hasValue("something"));
```

A *maybe* better approach is to collect all your assertions instead of stopping at the first one. You can use `SoftAssertions` in different ways, but I prefer this one:

```java
SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softly ->
    list.forEach(element -> softly.assertThat(element).isPresent())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assertThat(list).allSatisfy(o -> assertThat(o).hasValue("something")));
```

Javadoc :

- https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy(java.util.function.Consumer)
- https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractOptionalAssert.html#hasValue(VALUE)

For `List<Optional<T>>`, see also : https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractOptionalAssert.html#hasValueSatisfying(java.util.function.Consumer)

> Verifies that the actual Optional contains a value and gives this value to the given Consumer for further assertions. Should be used as a way of deeper asserting on the containing object, as further requirement(s) for the value.